# Get invalid timeframe of records by given their valid timeframe. (MSSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have table like below:

[image]

And I want to select out those products that their invalid timeframe like below, is there any efficient way that do not use cursor?
Notice that the timeframes may have overlappings.

[image]

Seems I need more explanation on the above two pics. The pic 1 shows valid timeframes of products. Each product may have multiple timeframes, and its timeframes may have overlappings. I want to select out the invalid timeframes of every products.

For product 1. its valid timeframes are [1/1/2013,1/1/2015] and [1/1/2014,1/1/2016], so it is invalid before 1/1/2013([NULL, 12/31/2012]), and after 1/1/2016([1/2/2016,NULL]), so pic 2 shows two records of product 1.

For product 2, it is also invalid between (1/1/2014,1/1/2015), so three records will shown.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what's an invalid timeframe? How do you recognize it?

Comment: @Mureinik: with the provided sample it's pretty clear what's invalid. All dates which are not between `ValidFrom` and `ValidThru`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter compared to what? the current date?

Comment: @Mureinik: no, all dates before and after the valid timeframes. `NULL` if there's no valid before/after the earliest/latest date of a valid timeframe. In the second query the column-names should be `InvalidFrom`/`InvalidThru`.

Comment: For product a, it has the valid timeframe of [1/1/2013,1/1/2015]. So its invalid timeframe is [minimumDate(NULL), 12/31/2012] and [1/2/2015, maximumDate(NULL)]

Comment: @TimSchmelter, you are right. I have updated the column names.

Comment: In your output ProductId 2 has three invalid date ranges.  Once you have this data how will you tell these rows apart?  I cannot see how you could join to this data, or identify when 1 row applies but the other 2 do not.  If you could elaborate on this perhaps we can help you?

Comment: This is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/514c0/8) I am playing with. Anyone is welcome to further add their input.

This is the very rough draft, but I think it can be achieved by this.
First step would be to generate year start and end date for a list (say from 2000 to 2099 and create a temporary table.
Then for each `productId` we need to get the list from the temporary table for the range of that `productId`. 

I still have to think for a logic for filtering the non necessary rows from above step. I will try to do it later after office.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/514c0/8

Comment: It will be headache in SQL-server. postgres have range datatype, which wloud turn this task to be quite simple. Just saying....